# Angular - Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::create() must be of the type array, object given

Tags: angular, laravel

I am trying to submit data from Angular-12 frontend into Laravel-8 api backend using this code:

Laravel api:

```
public function addCountry(StoreCountryRequest $request)
{
        $arr_country = Country::create([
            'name'          => $request->name,
            'capital'       => $request->capital,
            'created_by'    => Auth::user()->id,
            'created_at'    => date("Y-m-d H:i:s")
        ]);
        $country = Country::create($arr_country);
        return $this->success('Country successfully Added.', [
            'country'         => $country
        ]);
}
```

Angular:  Interface

```
export interface ICountry {
  id?: number;
  name: string;
  capital: string;
}
```

Service:

```
public addCountry(country: ICountry): Observable<ICountry> {
  return this.http.post<ICountry>(this.api.baseURL + 'add', country, this.httpOptions);
}
```

Component:

createForm!: FormGroup;
data1: any;

```
createCountry() {
  this.createForm = this.fb.group({
    name: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2), Validators.maxLength(100)]],
    capital: ['', [Validators.maxLength(100)]]
  });
}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.isLoading = true;
    this.createCountry();
}
```

submitCreateForm() {
this.isSubmitted = true;

```
// stop here if form is invalid
if (this.createForm.invalid) {
    return;
}
this.isLoading = true;

this.countriesService.addCountry(this.createForm.value).subscribe(res => {
  this.data1 = res;
  console.log(this.data1);
  },
  error => {
    this.store.dispatch(loadErrorMessagesSuccess(error));
    this.isLoading = false;
  });
  this.isLoading = false;
}
```

HTML:

```html
<form class="form-horizontal" [formGroup]="createForm" (ngSubmit)="submitCreateForm()">
  <div class="modal-body">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="name">Country Name:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
              <input type="text" formControlName="name" placeholder="Country Name" class="form-control" required/>
            </div>
            <div *ngIf="isSubmitted || (fc.name.touched && fc.name.invalid)">
              <div *ngIf="fc.name.hasError('required')">
                <div class="text-danger">
                  Country Name is required!
                </div>
              </div>
              <div *ngIf="fc.name.hasError('minlength')">
                <div class="text-danger">
                  Country Name cannot be less than 2 characters!
                </div>
              </div>
              <div *ngIf="fc.name.hasError('maxlength')">
                <div class="text-danger">
                  Country Name cannot be more than 100 characters!
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="capital">Capital:</label>
              <input type="text" formControlName="capital" placeholder="Capital" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div *ngIf="isSubmitted || (fc.capital.touched && fc.capital.invalid)">
              <div *ngIf="fc.capital.hasError('maxlength')">
                <div class="text-danger">
                  Capital cannot be more than 100 characters!
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-save" aria-hidden="true"></i> Save</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

When I submitted I got this on the console:   500 (Internal Server Error)

When I checked the error from the log file of the backend, I got this error:

> local.ERROR: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::create() must be of the type array, object given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Traits\ForwardsCalls.php on line 23 {"userId":1,"exception":"[object] (TypeError(code: 0): Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::create() must be of the type array, object given

How do I get this resolved?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You repeated a creation of country two times here

```
$arr_country = Country::create([
    'name'          => $request->name,
    'capital'       => $request->capital,
    'created_by'    => Auth::user()->id,
    'created_at'    => date("Y-m-d H:i:s")
]);
$country = Country::create($arr_country);
return $this->success('Country successfully Added.', [
    'country'         => $country
]);
```

You can doing

```
$arr_country = Country::create([
    'name'          => $request->name,
    'capital'       => $request->capital,
    'created_by'    => Auth::user()->id,
    'created_at'    => date("Y-m-d H:i:s")
]);
return $this->success('Country successfully Added.', [
    'country'         => $arr_country
]);
```

Have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

this is most probably causing error `$country = Country::create($arr_country);`.
in the previous step you already got a country. so

```
$country = Country::create([
       'name'          => $request->name,
       'capital'       => $request->capital,
       'created_by'    => Auth::user()->id,
       'created_at'    => date("Y-m-d H:i:s")
]);
return $this->success('Country successfully Added.', [
    'country'         => $country
]);
```

should work